# Highest index of a binary search

Tags: algorithm, search, binary-search

So I'm learning how to do a binary search and I understand the concept but what I don't understand is why we need

```
(right - left)
```

to get the highest index. I can't visualize this in my head :/

```
class Solution {
    public int search(int[] nums, int target) {
    int pivot;
    int left = 0;
    int right = nums.length - 1;
    while (left <= right) {
         pivot = left + (right - left) / 2;
         if (nums[pivot] == target) return pivot;
         if (target < nums[pivot]) right = pivot - 1;
         else left = pivot + 1;
    }
    return -1;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Note that `pivot = left + (right - left) / 2;` is the same as `pivot = (left + right) / 2;` and sets `pivot` to the middle point between `left` and `right`.

Comment: You are free to choose any pivot in the interval. If you choose poorly complexity becomes O(n²). If the array was already sorted (or is nearly sorted) taking the middle element is the best choice. For more details see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Choice_of_pivot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
left + (right - left) / 2
```

is the same as

```
(right + left) / 2
```

They both take the average of right and left. The purpose of using the former one is to prevent integer overflows. If `right + left` is bigger than the variable can carry, even though this variable can carry their average, the result will be wrong, because `right + left` will cause overflow.

On the other hand, first calculating `(right - left) / 2` and adding `left` prevents overflow.